# Dynamically save the Django form

Tags: javascript, python, django, dom, django-forms

I am trying not to use formset in my form. Instead of that, I'm trying to create the form dynamically and save all forms data in the DB.

I can create a dynamic form, but whenever I create multiple forms in "create order", it always saves the last forms data. For example, once I create 3 forms, and after saving the form, the table shows me only 3rd form data, which means it does not save all data together.

views.py

```
def create_order(request):
    from django import forms
    form = OrderForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            po_id = forms.cleaned_data['po_id']
            supplier = forms.cleaned_data['supplier']
            product = forms.cleaned_data['product']
            part = forms.cleaned_data['part']

            order = Order.objects.create(
                po_id=po_id,
                supplier=supplier,
                product=product,
                part=part,
            )
            forms.save()
            return redirect('order-list')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'store/addOrder.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['supplier', 'product', 'part','po_id']

        widgets = {
            'supplier': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'supplier'}),
            'product': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'product'}),
            'part': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'part'}),        
        }
```

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form-container"  novalidate="novalidate">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="form">            
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="po_id" class="control-label mb-1">ID</label>
        {{ form.po_id }}
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="supplier" class="control-label mb-1">Supplier</label>
        {{ form.supplier }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="product" class="control-label mb-1">Product</label>
        {{ form.product }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="part" class="control-label mb-1">Part Name</label>
        {{ form.part }}
    </div>     
</div>
<button id="add-form" type="button">Add Another Order</button>
    <div>
        <button id="payment-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
            <span id="payment-button-amount">Save</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    let poForm = document.querySelectorAll(".form")
    let container = document.querySelector("#form-container")
    let addButton = document.querySelector("#add-form")
    let totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")

    let formNum = poForm.length-1
    addButton.addEventListener('click', addForm)

    function addForm(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        let newForm = poForm[0].cloneNode(true)
        let formRegex = RegExp(`form-(\\d){1}-`,'g')

        formNum++
        newForm.innerHTML = newForm.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `form-${formNum}-`)
        container.insertBefore(newForm, addButton)
        
        totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum+1}`)
    }
</script>
```

What causes this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: What does the page source look like when you have 2 forms on the page?

Comment: After creating 2 forms on the page, the page source looks like this https://gist.github.com/TaufiqurRahman45/6703f624870d625c6cae53fb942bc95f